# How do I change startup sound in KDE Plasma?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gui, plasma, sound-theme

It's nice that KDE Plasma plays sounds on startup, but that awful click sound (or whatever they call it) is annoying. Anyone know how to change the startup sound in KDE Plasma?

Answer (score 5):

In **KDE Plasma 5.18**, follow

```
System Settings > Notifications > Applications > Plasma Workspace > Configure Events > Login
```

For **older versions**,

Follow the path from:

```
KDE Button > System Settings > Application and System Notifications
```

From here drill a little deeper:

```
Manage Notifications > Applications > Event Source > KDE Workspace
```

Scroll down to 'Login' and from there you can select a new sound. The screenshot below illustrates this on my own system:
[image]