# How to Get the Option to Choose a Startup Sound in 18.04?

Tags: sound

I went ahead and installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I'm trying to figure out how to be able to choose a startup login and logoff sound. I was told at one point that I could do this with gnome tweak tool however after going through it I didn't any options to do so. I can't exactly remember but I believe that either the native settings app or the Unity Tweak Tool on 16.04 had the options. Can someone help me solve this? Thanks for stopping by!

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn how to make/edit .desktop files and put inside for instance `aplay that.wav`
2. move that file to ~/.config/autostart

For logoff it is not so easy.

If you or somebody prefer KDE, here is easier: [How do I change startup sound in KDE Plasma?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790792/how-do-i-change-startup-sound-in-kde-plasma)